# Adding a class to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to add a class to my link_to for over an hour now. No matter what I try, I get an error.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Sign in', new_user_session_path) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to add `:class => "page-scroll btn-signin"` to both of my link_to lines.

Answer (score 2):

### I solved the problem

```
<%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => "page-scroll btn-signin" %>
```

This code works correctly.

Comment: This is the same code I've given above. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path, :class => "page-scroll btn-signin" %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => "page-scroll btn-signin" %>
```

[More info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

**EDIT**

Destructive actions should be performed as a form submission - [link](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#checklist)

use `button_to` on `Sign Out`.

```
<%= button_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method=>:delete, :class => "page-scroll btn-signin" %>
```

Comment: That worked! I tried that earlier and got an error. I must have forgot the "=>" or something.

Comment: @GVS, what is the new error? Your class names are same. Have you written any `js` code based on those classes?

Comment: There is no error. I click the "Sign out" and nothing happens.

Comment: No, I have not written any js based on that class.

Comment: @GVS, Edited answer.

Comment: No errors, but it still doesn't log me out. I removed the class tag and it didnt help. I replaced your code with my original and it works properly, but I have trouble adding a class